# Criteria API. Sort by latest child

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Im having huge difficulties to accomplish something that i would think should be pretty easy.

Basicly I have an OrderBean and an OrderInsertBean. They are both mapped entities to a mySQL table. An OrderBean can have multiple OrderInsertBeans and an OrderInsertBean has only one OrderBean.

Im writing Hibernate Criteria queries to build a dynamic query that will search and sort results from these tables. It mostly works fine, except when im trying to sort the orders by the next OrderInsertBean.

You see, an OrderInsertBean have an insertDate, and for each Order, I want to select the first OrderInsert that has an insertDate larger than today, and sort the orders by this date.

Easy enough in plain SQL. Could be written multiple ways, but this is one way to do it:

```
select o.*, (select min(oi2.insertDate) 
from AIDA_ORDER_INSERT oi2 where oi2.insertDate > curdate() 
and oi2.orderId = o.orderId) as insertDateNew 
from AIDA_ORDER o 
order by insertDateNew
```

But how the *** can this be written like a Hibernate Criteria query? Or a JPA 2 Criteria Query is also good.

This is as far as I have gotten...

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(OrderBean.class, "order");
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(OrderInsertBean.class, "oi");
subquery.add(Restrictions.ge("oi.insertDate", new Date()));

ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.min("oi.insertDate"));
projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("oi.orderId"));
subquery.setProjection(projectionList);

// How to add the subquery to the main query to get the desired results??

// Finally ordering the results:
crit.addOrder(Order.asc("insertDateNew"));
```

I think what i need is to somehow add the subquery to the criteria select list, give it an alias and then order by it...

But im stuck and dont know where to go.
Can anyone help a poor fella?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an `Order` to the criteria?

Like:

```
crit.addOrder(Order.asc("insertDateNew"));
```

Comment: Well, duh... Yeah. That addOrder is not the issue here. That i have under control. The difficult thing is how i can add the subquery to the main query to get the results defined by the above sql. Currently my code does not work at all.

Comment: The addOrder wasn't in your question when I commented, that seemed to be the obvious answer (for me).

Answer (score 0):

You already have mapped associations between Order and OrderInsert. Does this not work?

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(OrderBean.class, "order");

crit.createAlias("orderInserts", "oi");

crit.add(Restrictions.ge("oi.insertDate", new Date()));

ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.min("oi.insertDate"));
projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("oi.orderId"));
crit.setProjection(projectionList);

// Finally ordering the results:
crit.addOrder(Order.asc("oi.insertDateNew"));
```